# js fetch partial content: Range vs slice

Tags: javascript, blob, fetch-api

Reading only parts of an url file can be done with `Range` and `slice`, e.g.

```js
response = await fetch(url, {headers: {Range: `bytes=990-999`}});
buf = await response.text();
// or
response = await fetch(url);
blob = await response.blob();
buf = await blob.slice(990, 1000).text();
```

What is difference between both method?
In particular is `Range` faster, when reading small parts of large files?

I noticed that `Range` allows for multiple ranges. Is there more one should know (advantages)?

Comment: Slice is client side, range is server side!?

Comment: "...small parts of large files" is a good hint.  Use range.

Comment: @luk2302 Might be a good point.